# ASP.NET Core Url.Action return empty string

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, razor, url.action

After 3 hours browsing on stackoverflow I don't find solution of my problem.
So I suspect something in my project is special.

I have a ASP.NET Core (2.0) WebApplications Project on Visual Studios 2017. I try to make a ajax call from my Kalender.cshtml file:

```
return $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: myurl,
    data: '{}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {        //REQUEST SUCCESS
        alert(result);
    },
```

with myurl:

```
var myurl = '@Url.Action("EventsRead","Kalender")';
```

but I recognize that **alert(myurl)** return an empty string. So the ajax call must fail. I guess the url should something like:

```
/Kalender/EventsRead
```

but if I use this, ajax return 404 Not found.

My Kalender.cshtml.cs Action looks like:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult EventsRead()
{
    //DATABASE READOUT        
    var events = DataBase.Events.ToList();
    return new JsonResult(events);
}
```

And the class of the PageModel looks like:

```
public class KalenderModel : PageModel
```

Here is everything auto generated. I try about 100 different version but never get a breakpoint into the `EventsRead()` action.

SIDE INFORMATION:

In my Startup.cs I suppress AntiforgeryToken:

```
services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.ConfigureFilter(new IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
});
```

I really need some help before I get insane, thankful for any response.
Martin

Answer (score 4):

Everybody who interested into the solution:

I changed in Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        //ROUTES DEFAULT SETTINGS
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

to:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        //ROUTES CUSTOM SETTINGS
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
```

after this

```
'@Url.Action("TestGet","Kalender")'
```

will return correkt path.

Now I go to my bed and cry.

Answer (score 0):

Your Controller setup looks just fine. When you used `/Kalender/EventsRead` as url and have a response 404 because of your data field. You've put curly braces as string. Try this in your ajax call

```
return $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/Kalender/EventsRead',
    data:{},
    success: function (result) {        //REQUEST SUCCESS
        console.log(result);
    },
    error: function (response){
        console.log(response)
    });
```

This may help you.

Comment: still Error EventsRead: Not Found (404) - Not Found. :/

Comment: If you call ajax from script written in `$(document).ready(function())` of you view page where you actually can use razor, only  from there `@Url.Action()` will work. Anyway for test purpose, call that ajax on a button click and drop `data`, `dataType` and `contentType` field. Make it a simple test. Because it doesn't seem to be a problem here

Comment: In addition make your return from the controller function like
`return json(result, JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet)`

Comment: I hope I understand it correctly: I call **'@Url.Action("EventsRead", "Kalender")';** before and after **$(document).ready(function () {** both will return an empty string. And in **Newtonsoft.Json** is **JsonRequestBehaviour** not available, so I have to return string or JsonResult.

Comment: Second: I do everything like you said. I create a button, add **onclick="TestAction()"**, write a TestAction function with Ajax call and drop **data**, **dataType** and **contentType**. I try it as **'GET'** and as **'POST'**. As **static** and as **non-static**. With Token **[HttpGet]**, **[HttpPost]**, **and nothing**. All trials response Error 404.