# Url.Action is wrong with Knockout + Asp.Net MVC Core 2.2

Tags: knockout.js, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to generate a table containing a link for each row with knockout and Asp.Net Core 2.2. Actually I want the whole row to be clickable later, for this example I added it as a table field though.

The path for the `@Url.Action("MyAction", "My")` gets generated wrongly though. Both of them are completely empty. Neither the controller, nor the action appear in the generated link.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: searchResults">
  <tr>
    <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
    <td>
      <a data-bind="attr: { href: '@Url.Action("MyAction", "My")/' + id}">
        Click
      </a>
    </td>
    <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: date"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

"My" is the controller "MyController". "MyAction" is the name of the action method I want to call on click. I do have another controller, for a different path. The one I am trying to use is this:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IWebServiceFactory webServiceFactory;

    public MyController(IWebServiceFactory webServiceFactory)
    {
        this.webServiceFactory = webServiceFactory;
    }

    // GET: api/MyAction/{GUID}
    [HttpGet("{id:Guid}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> MyAction(Guid id)
    {
        var result = await webServiceFactory.GetWebService().GetFileAsync(id);
        var memory = new MemoryStream();
        await result .Stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
        memory.Position = 0;
        return File(memory, "application/unknown", result.FileName);
    }
}
```

I thought maybe it is because the controller route does not use any action, but even after adding the action to the route, the results were the same.

I am using Mvc with the default route in `Startup.cs`:

```
app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
```

This is the actual output I am getting:

```
<a data-bind="attr: { href: '/' + id }" href="/173a4cec-a258-4ebb-d28e-08d6cee0966c">Click</a>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see any reason that wouldn't work. In fact when I copy it to my own MVC project and replace the controller names with ones I have the link comes out as expected. I would look more closely at your controller and maybe the routing setup

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49907003/3082296

Comment: @adiga Sadly not. I am using app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute() already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid `Url.Action` from trying to render a MVC view related url instead of an Api endpoint url,
use [`@Url.RouteUrl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.urlhelperextensions.routeurl?view=aspnetcore-2.2) with a route-name that has been applied to the given Api controller action method; eg. `ApiMyMyActionGuidRoute`

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{   
    [HttpGet("{id:Guid}", Name ="ApiMyMyActionGuidRoute")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> MyAction(Guid id)
    {
        // Your implementation goes here ...
    }
}
```

In your view, render the url via `@Url.Route`.
Note that you will have to apply a dummy `Guid` value for the `id` argument as this argument is mandatory on the action method (`MyAction(Guid id)`).

Since this `id` value is being applied via a `Knockout` binding, you first have to remove the dummy one from the generated url before applying it in the `Knockout` `data-bind` expression.

```
@{  
    var routeUrl = Url.RouteUrl("ApiMyMyActionGuidRoute", new { id = Guid.Empty });
    // routeUrl = "/api/My/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
    routeUrl = routeUrl.Substring(0, routeUrl.LastIndexOf("/"));
    // routeUrl = "/api/My"
}
<p><a data-bind="attr: { href: '@routeUrl/' + id }">Click</a></p>
```

This will generate the html markup below having the correct Api endpoint url onto which `Knockout` will apply the `id` argument value.

```
<p><a data-bind="attr: { href: '/api/My/' + id }">Click</a></p>
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot. Im surprised you have to specify a default value to generate a correct route.